# Populate database with Divi contact form module in wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress

I created a registration form using the divi module which sends an email holding the information in the form but I also want to save those inputs in a database. I've spent hours looking on internet for similar questions and the only one I found was [this](https://www.reddit.com/r/webdev/comments/863uwu/populating_a_database_or_excel_sheet_with_the/) which I follow and I created a new table in my database and then created a plugin to hold the script but it never enters the if condition.

How can I achieve the functionality I'm looking?. I'm completely new to wordpress and php so apologies if my question and approached seemed silly

```
<?php
/**
* Plugin Name: Very First Plugin
* Plugin URI: https://www.yourwebsiteurl.com/
* Description: This is the very first plugin I ever created.
* Version: 1.0
* Author: Your Name Here
* Author URI: http://yourwebsiteurl.com/
**/
// Silence is golden.

function td_divi_contact_form_capture( $content ) {
    $html = "<script>console.log('PHPa: ".count( $_POST )."');</script>";

echo($html);
// The preg_match looks for the div with the "thank you" message to be populated
if (
    // count( $_POST ) > 0 && 
    // array_key_exists( '_wpnonce-et-pb-contact-form-submitted', $_POST ) && 
    preg_match( '%<div class="et-pb-contact-message"><p>[^<]+</p></div>%s', $content) ) {

    $html = "<script>console.log('PsHP: ".count( $_POST )."');</script>";

    echo($html);
    // $form_fields = [];
    // $form_id     = false;
    // foreach ( $_POST as $key => $val ) {
        //  if ( preg_match( '/^et_pb_contact_(.+)_(\d)+$/', $key, $parts ) ) {
            //      $field_name = $parts[1];
            //      if ( $field_name == 'email_fields' || $field_name == 'email_hidden_fields' ) {
                //          $form_id = $parts[2];
                //      } else {
                    //          $form_fields[ $field_name ] = $val;
                    //      }
                    //  }
                    // }
                    // if ( count( $form_fields ) > 0 ) {
                        //  td_divi_contact_form_save( 
                            //                         trim( $_POST['_wp_http_referer'], '/' ), 
                            //                         $form_id, 
                            //                         $form_fields 
                            //                     );
                            // }
}
return $content;
}

add_filter( 'the_content', 'td_divi_contact_form_capture', 20);
```

Comment: Use a forms plugin like gravity forms or ninja forms or formidable forms etc